# Twilio Authy 2FA for OneCode C# Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, curl, twilio

I am developing a web application using C# that uses 2 factor authentication during Sign Up. I have already tried 2FA using Nexmo's API. It worked fine. All I had to do was call their API and speciy the 'to' number. Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Start(string to)
{
    var start = NumberVerify.Verify(new NumberVerify.VerifyRequest
    {
        number = to,
        brand = "NexmoQS"
    });
    Session["requestID"] = start.request_id;

    return View();
}
```

Now, I decided to give Twilio a try. I came across Authy and it's process. I found their 2FA API [here](https://www.twilio.com/two-factor-authentication/api#onecode). But I don't understand where should I enter the 'to' number as specified in Nexmo. I am a beginner and using .NET(C#) code snippet. Here is the code snippet. Please help me configure this code as I am able to do in Nexmo.

```
public static async Task VerifyPhoneAsync()
  {
    // Create client
    var client = new HttpClient();

    // Add authentication header
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authy-API-Key", AuthyAPIKey);

    // https://api.authy.com/protected/$AUTHY_API_FORMAT/phones/verification/check?phone_number=$USER_PHONE&country_code=$USER_COUNTRY&verification_code=$VERIFY_CODE
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/check?phone_number=5558675309&country_code=1&verification_code=3043");

    // Get the response content.
    HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

    // Get the stream of the content.
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
      {
        // Write the output.
        Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
      }
    }
```

They have given a cURL implementation of their api [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy/authy-totp#requesting-sms-codes), please help me configure it in C#.

```
curl "http://api.authy.com/protected/json/users/new?api_key=d57d919d11e6b221c9bf6f7c882028f9" \
-d user[email]="user@domain.com" \
-d user[cellphone]="317-338-9302" \
-d user[country_code]="54"
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Any error? What response you get from the API ?

Comment: I am not able to run this.. It says not able to find `AuthyAPIKey`

Comment: What is it that says that?

Comment: From where you are getting `AuthyAPIKey` ? What is the importance if that? Did you copy paste code from somewhere? Did you go thru the documentation of this API?

Comment: `AuthyAPIKey` is present as a parameter in the function `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authy-API-Key", AuthyAPIKey);` here in the api code that I posted. I am assuming I have to replace the string with my api key that I have but still `AuthyAPIKey` is giving error that it is not found. Also where am I supposed to enter the receiver's number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When making a call to the API, you do need to add the `X-Authy-API-Key` header as well as a URL parameter `api_key`. Also, to start the process of verifying a number you should be making a POST request with the data you need to send to the API.

[The two bits of data that you need are the phone number and the country code for that phone number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy/authy-phone-verification-api#parameters). Though you can set some other values, like the way you want to send the verification code (`via` sms or call).

I would update your code to look like this:

```
public static async Task StartVerifyPhoneAsync()
  {
    // Create client
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var AuthyAPIKey = 'YOUR AUTHY API KEY';

    // Add authentication header
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authy-API-Key", AuthyAPIKey);

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "phone_number", "PHONE NUMBER TO VERIFY" },
      { "country_code", "COUNTRY CODE FOR PHONE NUMBER" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var url = $"https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start?api_key={AuthyAPIKey}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    // do something with the response
  }
```

Then when the user enters the code, you need to check it. Again you should add the API key as a header and send as a URL parameter too, along with the phone number, country code and the verification code the user entered, this time as a GET request.

```
public static async Task CheckVerifyPhoneAsync()
  {
    // Create client
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var AuthyAPIKey = 'YOUR AUTHY API KEY';

    // Add authentication header
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authy-API-Key", AuthyAPIKey);

    var phone_number = "PHONE NUMBER TO VERIFY";
    var country_code = "COUNTRY CODE FOR PHONE NUMBER";
    var verification_code = "THE CODE ENTERED BY THE USER";
    var url = $"https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start?api_key={AuthyAPIKey}&phone_number={phone_number}&country_code={country_code}&verification_code={verification_code}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    // do something with the response
  }
```

Let me know if that helps at all.